# Edit Leaflet multipolygons

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm using the [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) library to allow in map editing of geojson shapes. On multipolygon types though, I get the error message `TypeError: layer.options is undefined` from the  library.

This looks like the same issue referenced [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/124). Is there a workaround for this that allows drawing, editing, and deleting multipolygon type geojson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround is just splitting the `MultiPolygon` type geojson into several `Polygon`s.

```
if (shape.type === "MultiPolygon") {
  shape.coordinates.forEach(function(shapeCoords, i) {
    var polygon = {type:"Polygon", coordinates: shapeCoords};
    L.geoJson(polygon, {
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        featureGroup.addLayer(layer);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could also use [Leaflet.PM](https://github.com/codeofsumit/leaflet.pm), a drawing library for leaflet that is supporting MultiPolygons.

Add your geojson shapes via L.geoJson and leaflet.pm can handle it's editing, including holes.

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of leaflet.PM